# Ignore Redis on Local Server

Tags: redis, windows, xampp

We had redis installed on our remote server, so we had Cm_RedisSession `<active>` set to `true`. However, we always get an error when running local server due to Redis not installed.

Is there a way for magento to ignore it without modifying the xml file?

Note that I cannot install anything (including redis) on my local server due to user permissions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just fall back to default sessions in your app/etc/local.xml file.

`<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>`

and remove the redis_session configuration